# How to diff the current text and the clipboard?

Tags: vimdiff, os-clipboard

How to create a diff of the current text and the clipboard?

It could result in a vertical split showing the clipboard content, and a normal diff between them.
Opening a vertical split, pasting and diffing should work, but there are the commands `:diffsplit` and `:diffthis`, so I feel I may be missing something.

Comment: 1. What do you call "the clipboard"? 2. What did you try?

Comment: i mean the system clipboard, like when cutting elsewhere with Ctrl-C and pasting with `p`in vim. I tried to manually create two documents to diff, but that is more like a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Hi @Volker, I try to close the question. Do you still have one aspect of your question that is not answered and if so which one? Otherwise I'll be glad if you could accept one answer to allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a variant of the Diff recipe:

```
function! DiffClipboard()
    let ft=&ft
    vertical new
    setlocal bufhidden=wipe buftype=nofile nobuflisted noswapfile
    :1put
    silent 0d_
    diffthis
    setlocal nomodifiable
    execute "set ft=" . ft
    wincmd p
    diffthis
endfunction
command! DiffClipboard call DiffClipboard()
```

Comment: Consider `normal! p` or just `put`

Comment: should that be `:0put +`?

Comment: Could be but to make sure the number of the line `:1put +`  and keep the `silent 0d_` works better for me. On Windows the clipboard is either `"` or `*` with `set unnamed`. Why do you prefer `+` over `"`?

Comment: Did you mean "either `*` or `+`"?

Comment: You are right `*` or `+`